# Replace dynamic word using sed command

Tags: linux, sed, regular-expression, search, replace

I have a requirement where we need to replace a word in a file which can be different everytime I execute the script, the content of the file is

```
class DynamicContentToReplace > Something
```

Here I need to use sed command to replace [DynamicContentToReplace] with RequiredContent. The [DynamicContentToReplace] could include everything except white spaces.

Assumptions we can take is that the file will only contain one such line containing `class` word

Desired Output

```
class RequiredContent > Something
```

I have tried the following command
`sed -e "s/\(class \)\([^\s]+\)/\1RequiredContent/"` but it still does not replace the content. What am i missing here. I have gone through [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=sed%20replace%20a%20word%20surrounded%20by%20white%20spaces&rlz=1C5GCEM_enIN957IN958&oq=sed%20replace%20a%20word%20surrounded%20by%20white%20spaces&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64l3.14053j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) post as well. But couldn't get the solution.

Comment: What is the desired output ? What's the `> Something` part ? Something on the same line?

Comment: @golder3 updated the desired output, and yes `> Something` part is on the same line.

Comment: What is unique about that line? Can `class` appear on any other lines? Can `foo bar >` appear on other lines? How can we identify the bit that needs to change?

Comment: @terdon updated the question. yes  `class` word will only appear once in the entire file. We can identify the word to replace using that

Answer (score 4):

- For Basic Regex, you need to escape the `+` quantifier.
- `\+` is a GNU extension, you may need to use `*` or `\{1,\}` instead.
- Use `[^[:space:]]` or simply `[^ ]` instead of `[^\s]`. With GNU `sed` you could also use `\S` for anything but whitespace.
- No need to capture the second group, as you don't use `\2` anywhere.
- If you have only one `sed` command, there is no need for `-e`
- You might want to add `^` in front of `class` to not replace unwanted things like `instance=my_class_something()`

Use:

```
sed 's/^\(class \)[^[:space:]]*/\1RequiredContent/'
```

or use Extended Regex (`sed -E`):

```
sed -E 's/^(class )\S+/\1RequiredContent/'
```

Comment: for me the first solution does not work, it does not replace anything. The second one using extended Regex does. Thanks @pLumo

Comment: Note that `\+`, `\S`, `\s` are GNU extensions (`\s`/`\S` obviously inspired from `perl`)

Comment: also for extended regeX?

Comment: `-E` is from BSD `sed`. GNU `sed` had `-r` for that. GNU `sed` later added a hidden -E for compatibility with BSD, and later unhid it as POSIX plans to add it to standard `sed` (already there in drafts of the next version). But in any case, there's no `\s` / `\S` in standard BRE nor EREs. There is `+` in standard ERE, the standard BRE equivalent being `\{1,\}`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using perl regexp operators, why not just use perl?

```
perl -pe 's/\bclass\s+\K\S+/RequiredContent/g' < your-file
```

- `\b` is a word boundary operator, it will match as long as there's no word character before `class`.
- `\s` matches any whitespace character (limited to ASCII ones as we did not tell `perl` to decode the input in the user's locale or UTF-8¹, so the input is interpreted as if encoded in ISO8859-1 (thankfully the 0xa0 byte, ISO8859-1's non-breaking space encoding not being considered whitespace as long as you don't add the `u` flag to that `s`ubstitution).
- `\K` resets the start of the matched string, so only what's matched after that will be replaced, so you don't need to capture what's before to add it back in the replacement.
- `\S` is any non-whitespace. In perl, that's equivalent to `[^\s]` while in `sed`, `[^\s]` would match any character other than `\` and `s`.

---

<sup>¹ assuming the `PERL_UNICODE` environment variable is not set</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I propose this, assuming 'class' is always there ans is at the start of the line:

```bsh
$ sed 's/^class [^ ]*/class RequiredContent/'
class RequiredContent > Something
```

---

- `[^ ]*` substitue everything that's not a blank after 'class ' with 'class ' plus the required new string.